# Error : Sorry this page not available on facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I have just integrated the `facebook` SDK in android native app, I created a app on `facebook` dashboard to integrate a `facebook` SDK in android native app.

I am successfully posted the message on the `facebook` through my android native app, it shows my app name "Sooligan", when I am clicking on this "Sooligan" it is redirecting to me on page not available.

Please see attached screenshots.

[image: Screenshot1]

Clicking on Sooligin it is redirected to below page

[image: Screenshot2]

Guys any way to solve this problem so that it should open any page which I want or anything related to that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this simply add the website in the platform also, there I have added my website URL which I want to open for ex : www.google.com

Answer (score 0):

Under Basic Info in your app settings on Facebook you will need to set your Canvas URL. When that page is called it will send the variable fb_source which will tell you if it came from the application or your facebook page, etc. You can then choose to redirect it however you want (if you want to).

Comment: It is redirecting to me on facebook apps page, I want to simply clicking on this app should redirect to my own custom URL like www.yahoo.com